# Assembly project and subproject only, leave dependencies as dependencies

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I have an SBT project A which depends on a project B.
Both of them have their maven dependencies.
I want to assemble A and B into a single jar to publish to maven without their dependencies bundled into jar, just leave them as maven dependencies.

How is it possible with sbt-assembly?